# Enable MathJAX?

Tags: feature-request

Someone asked a question about why picked guitar strings sound different from finger-plucked strings.  A complete answer to this is very math-heavy for this site.

I posted my answer here: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/84894/474

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be one of the SE sites that has MathJAX enabled, so my equations are just the raw TeX code.  Can MathJAX be enabled to allow proper rendering of the answer?

Comment: From seeing similar questions elsewhere in the network, the reason it's not deployed globally is that it's a relatively large javascript file and SE doesn't want to slow down all page loads on sites where it'd be very rarely used.

Comment: @DanNeely Presumably standard caching techniques come into play when it comes to the download; and can the file not be referenced only in pages where it is needed? I don't see why it would need to slow down all page loads...

Comment: @topomorto  Performance testing with mathjax dis/enabled  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on#204003  I've seen several questions/answers proposing letting mathjax be turned on at a per question level on meta.se; but none received an official response.

Comment: @DanNeely it doesn't slow down page loads. It can be loaded asynchronously, after all the content is downloaded. And yes, topo morto is right about caching. Lots of the time, the browser doesn't even need to download the library.

Comment: @DanNeely I am certain that it would be *possible* to enable MathJAX in a way that didn't slow down pages that didn't need it. Of course it may be that SE's current architecture doesn't lend itself to that.

Comment: @topomorto feel free to make the case on meta.SE; I'm virtually certain the devs aren't paying attention to anything here.

Answer (score 5):

Enabling MathJax is not without downsides, as Dan Neely has pointed out. It also can be a challenge on the user end, as I've experienced on Math.SE.

To me, it doesn't seem overall worth it for the very rare cases where math would be use in a Music.SE answer, and as we've seen, images can work for formulae in those cases. It makes sense on other Stacks because of the ubiquity of math on those Stacks, not so much here.